# How do I add older SDKs to my system?

Tags: ios, xcode, rubymotion

I am running on MacOS Sierra. I downloaded/upgraded my X Code.

Currently, if I run `xcodebuild -showsdks` it reveals that I have iOS SDK 10.0.

I need to add support for iOS 9.3. How do I do this?

Do I need to download XCode 7.3?

**EDIT:**

I need iOS SDK 9.3 specifically -- no version after, because of RubyMotion.

Comment: try changing the minimum sdk requirement in the application settings

Comment: edited question

Comment: what do you mean by "specifically" here?

Comment: ERROR! You are using RubyMotion Starter. Only iOS 9.3 is supported in this release. If you would like to target older or newer (in beta) versions of iOS you can purchase a paid subscription.

Answer (score 2):

iOS 9.3 is still supported with Xcode 8. There shouldn't be any issues.

For anything less than iOS 8, you will have to download Xcode 7 series.

Comment: only 10.0 is avail. 9.3 i need specifically for RubyMotion

Comment: You can try changing the deployment target - minimum supported version.

Answer (score 1):

No need for older Xcode. Just open your project, open projects settings, choose your target and change "General -> Deployment Info -> Deployment Target" to needed value (e.g. `9.3`)

**Update for your edit:** yes, to get older SDK version you need to download older Xcode, unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

You can check by downloading simulator of iOS 9 only, Go to xcode preference and download required simulator, check screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: this looks like what I need. checking now.

Comment: Ok, it's downloaded but it doesn't show up when I run `xcodebuild -showsdks`. Is there another step to use it?